# laravel eloquent model not able to store decimal values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and PHP 7.3 where
I have to store decimal fields in database

table column decription look like this

```
'commission_percentage', 'decimal(12,4)'
'commission_amount', 'decimal(12,4)'
```

And I'm trying to store decimal value for this column in mysql using eloquent model.

And here is the example code for that.

```
$per = 10.23;
$commission = 2.1234;
$createArr = [    
                  'commission_percentage' => $per,
                  'commission_amount' =>  $commission
             ];
            
MyModel::create($createArr);
```

my eloquent model look like

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'my_table';
    protected $guarded = ['id'];
    protected $casts = [
        'commission_percentage' => 'decimal:4',
        'commission_amount' => 'decimal:4'
    ];

}
```

And I have also tried

```
protected $casts = [
            'commission_percentage' => 'float',
            'commission_amount' => 'float'
        ];
```

But no luck. I still get 10.0000 and 2.0000 inside the DB.

Even I have tried inserting value's using raw query

```
DB::insert('insert into my_table (commission_percentage,commission_amount ) values(?, ?)', [$per, $commission]);
```

But hard luck on that too as I still get 10.0000 and 2.0000 inside the DB.

Comment: it should have been handled by the migration itself. can you provide the original migration code for that fileds?

Comment: Can you add the example code you used ? you might have sent values with `,` comma as decimal seperation

Comment: @N69S I have added the example code. And I havn't sent value with ` ,` comma as decimal seperation.

Comment: Then check your database directly for the field format type. one of the two is wrong, input or DB.

Comment: @sdebarun We don't have any migration for this. But the issue is with eloquent model or laravel database package which is not saving the value as required.

Comment: @N69S I have already shared the column description as it is decimal(12,4) and if I run insert quety on mysql serve 
" insert into my_table (commission_percentage,commission_amount ) values(10.23, 2.1234) " then I'm able to see desired output

Comment: remove everything in the $casts attribute and run a static example `DB::insert('insert into my_table (commission_percentage,commission_amount ) values(?, ?)', [1.23, 2.1234])`

Comment: @N69S I have removed everything from $cast and excuted the static query but still not able to get descired output

Comment: how are you checking the output ?

Comment: @N69S Directly on databse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230876/discussion-between-keshav-kothari-and-n69s).

Comment: just joined the chat, and you left it already. Just one simple point, running the static query with eloquent QB is like running a query in the DB CLI. There is an issue with your testing/verification.

Answer (score 0):

The work around that I have found for this is to typecast the variable into "string"

```
$per = 10.23;
$commission = 2.1234;
$createArr = [    
                  'commission_percentage' => (string) $per,
                  'commission_amount' => (string) $commission
             ];
            
MyModel::create($createArr);
```